# Android: Selecting Items in a Spinner and calculating their total price + getting ID of each Item upon a Button Click

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am very new to android development and to StackOverflow so don't mind if I have not used the correct words for my question.
I am implementing a spinner for items with their images and prices.
First of all, all this work is going in a Class that extends from BaseAdapter according to my needs.
In getView of the spinner I set the spinner view.
Now in the getView I want that, when a user selects an Item in the Spinner, the Button Click Listener should calculate the total price of items (first calculate the total in one Row and at the end of Button Click calculate the total of all rows) and then give me the ID of each Item.
I can implement the button click listener but don't know how to do all that stuff with the Spinner, so please help me doing that.
As my reputation is not more than 10, I cannot share an image.
What I have done up till now is here:

```
public class Base_Adapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ImageView image;
    TextView name, price;

    Context context ;
    ArrayList<ItemDetails> IDetails; //The item class which have methods and fields
     RelativeLayout R_Layout;
     Activity activit;
    public  Base_Adapter(Context context , ArrayList<ItemDetails> li) 
    {
        this.context = context;
        IDetails = li;

    }

    public void setLayout(Activity activity, RelativeLayout layout){
        R_Layout = layout;
        this.activit = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return IDetails.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View CV, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        LayoutInflater infleter = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(CV == null)
        {
            CV = infleter.inflate(R.layout.base_adapter, null);
        }

        final ItemDetails item = IDetails.get(position);
        int min =1;
        int max = Integer.parseInt(item.totall_Available());
        ArrayList<String> A_list= new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=1;i<=max;i++)
        {
             A_list.add("Number of Items :"+i);
        }

         image = (ImageView) CV.findViewById(R.id.Item_image);
         name = (TextView) CV.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
         price = (TextView) CV.findViewById(R.id.item_price);

        final Spinner quantity = (Spinner) CV.findViewById(R.id.items);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,  R.layout.spinner_textview, A_list);
        quantity.setAdapter(adapter);


        price.setText(""+item.price());
        name.setText(item.name());

        return CV;


    }
 //Here in some place the button should calculate   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to implement OnItemSelectedListener then you access the selected item and do things with it. Here is an example from some old code of mine:

```
Post implements OnItemSelectedListener,
```

...

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View stringDate, int arg2, long arg3) {
        if (spinner.getId() == R.id.platform) {
            platform = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        } else {
            day = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
    }
```